# How to group a CSV file by a column using Perl?

Tags: perl, csv

I have data like:

```
Date    client  market  currency    ordersQty
5/12/2013   AAA ASE Doller  50
6/12/2013   BBB BSE pound   100
10/12/2013  CCC ASE pound   500
```

I would like to group this data by the month and the market, splitting it into multiple CSV files.

Comment: what have you tried? Have you considered [Parse::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::CSV) or any of the other csv modules on cpan. Also, your data seems to be fixed length. If it contains only ASCII characters, you could use `unpack` with the `A` template.

Comment: `Time::Piece` (strptime) is good for date parsing. If you show us some code, we can offer specific examples.

Answer (score 1):

Perl from command line (all `X` should be replaced with appropriate number)

```
perl -Mautodie -F'[\s/]+' -ane'
  if ($. ==1) { $h = $_; next }
  $k = "StatReport_$F[X]_$F[X]$F[X].csv";
  if (!$f{$k}) { open($f{$k}, ">", $k); s/^/$h/ }
  print { $f{$k} } $_;
' file
```

Comment: Ok, first one is 4. :)